# How to join two columns from one table to a different table based matching criteria in SAS

Tags: sql, join, sas, left-join, proc-sql

I am trying to join the columns "Type2" and "Measurement2" from table "Update" to the table "Have". I want the columns to align where column "Subject1" in table "Have" matches column "Subject2" in table "update", and column "Procedure1" in table "Have" matches column "Procedure2" in table "Update".Thank you in advance.

```
data Have;
    input Subject1 Type1 :$12. Date1 &:anydtdte. Procedure1 :$12. Measurement1;
    format date yymmdd10.;
    datalines;

500   Initial    15 AUG 2017      Invasive    20 
500   Initial    15 AUG 2017     Surface      35   
428   Initial     3 JUL 2017     Outer        10 
765   Initial     20 JUL 2019     Other       19  
610   Initial     17 Mar 2018     Invasive    17 
;

data Update;
    input Subject2 Type2 :$12. Date2 &:anydtdte. Procedure2 :$12. Measurement2;
    format date yymmdd10.;
    datalines;

500   Followup   15 AUG 2018     Invasive     54 
428   Followup    15 AUG 2018      Outer      29 
765   Seventh     3 AUG 2018      Other       13 
500   Followup    3 JUL 2018      Surface     98 
610   Third       20 AUG 2019     Invasive    66  
;
```

Comment: What do you mean "grouped by"?  You normally only use a GROUP BY clause when you are going to use an aggregate function. What aggregate do you want to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a join between two tables ??

```
Select distinct have.*, update.type2, update.measurement2 
from have
left join update
on
have.subject1 = update.subject2
and have.procedure1 = update.procedure2
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining two data sets based on a key (your subject and procedure) is performed using a `MERGE` according to the *group* variables named in a `BY` statement.  Both data sets need the same BY variables.

Example code:

- `MERGE` requires sorted data, so that will have to occur first.
- Data set option `rename=` is used to create common names for the `BY` statement.

```
proc sort data=Have;    by Subject1 Procedure1;
proc sort data=Updates; by Subject2 Procedure2;

data combined;
  * trick: force these variables to be first two columns in output data set;
  retain subject procedure;

  merge
    have    (rename=(subject1=subject procedure1=procedure))
    updates (rename=(subject2=subject procedure2=procedure))
  ;
  by subject procedure;
run;
```

[image]

Example data:

```
data Have;
attrib
  Subject1 length=8
  Type1 length=$12
  Date1 informat=anydtdte. format=yymmdd10.
  Procedure1 length=$12
  Measurement1 length=8
;
input 
Subject1& Type1&   Date1&       Procedure1& Measurement1&; datalines;
500       Initial  15 AUG 2017  Invasive    20 
500       Initial  15 AUG 2017  Surface     35   
428       Initial   3 JUL 2017  Outer       10 
765       Initial  20 JUL 2019  Other       19  
610       Initial  17 Mar 2018  Invasive    17 
;

data Updates;
attrib
  Subject2 length=8
  Type2 length=$12
  Date2 informat=anydtdte. format=yymmdd10.
  Procedure2 length=$12
  Measurement2 length=8
;
input 
Subject2& Type2&    Date2&       Procedure2& Measurement2&; datalines;
500       Followup  15 AUG 2018  Invasive    54 
428       Followup  15 AUG 2018  Outer       29 
765       Seventh    3 AUG 2018  Other       13 
500       Followup   3 JUL 2018  Surface     98 
610       Third     20 AUG 2019  Invasive    66  
;
```